# Minecraft /testfor item rotated a certain way in an item frame

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-commands

Is there a way to set a command block to detect if an item frame has a certain item in it rotated to a certain position?

Answer (score 1):

A quick internet search yielded a video by Dragnoz.

The command he uses:

```
/testfor @e[type=ItemFrame] {TileX:-819,TileY:32,TileZ:-245,Facing:3b,ItemRotation:3b}
```

You would have to change the numbers to match your situation.

---

Update: The type has changed to `item_frame`.  Also, you do not have to specify `Facing`, which will accept an item frame in the specified block facing any direction.  Item rotation is a number between 0 and 7.  You can also specify the item with the `Item` tag.

Here is a command which will run in 1.12.2:

```
/testfor @e[type=item_frame] {TileX:<x>,TileY:<y>,TileZ:<z>,ItemRotation:0b}
```

[Here is the wiki on item frame data values](https://minecraft.wiki/w/Item_Frame#Data_values) for more information.